# Is there a way to catch click events earlier than .stopPropagation() gets executed onclick?

Tags: javascript, events, click, preventdefault, stoppropagation

The purpose of `document.body.onclick = e => console.log(e.target);` is to catch all clicks. Unfortunately, the click on the first link won't be displayed in the console. Is there a way to grab links from the page, even those that have `stopPropagation()`?

https://jsfiddle.net/htLw9cxy/

```js
function myFuncCanNotBeEdited(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  //...
  //and do some other important code here
}

document.body.onclick = e => console.log(e.target);
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;">
    <a href="#" onclick="myFuncCanNotBeEdited(event);">Edit</a>
    <a href="#">Remove</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're using inline JavaScript instead of event listeners?

Comment: You would have to repeat your body click code in your link click code (maybe turn it into a function that can be called in both?) - the point of stop propagation is to stop the click event bubbling up to the parent - if you want it to bubble up then don't stop it

Comment: FYI, anchors shouldn't be used for actions. Use buttons (or other elements with a button role attribute).

Comment: > Is there some reason you're using inline JavaScript instead of event listeners? - No, there isn't. Will the correct answer on the question be changed, if the code gets refactored?

Comment: >FYI, anchors shouldn't be used for actions. Use buttons (or other elements with a button role attribute).    Thank you, but anchors used for their purposes, as supposed to. However, the external js service should additionally track the clicks to check if the session was lost and notify user, if the session was lost.

Comment: There is, but it's really hacky, do you want to see it ?

Comment: >You would have to repeat your body click code in your link click code  > there are tons of links and buttons on the page with different functions. The common solution is preferable (if exists), without modification every <a>'s or <button>'s logic.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is really hacky, so be careful as it involve modifying built in prototype.

You can intercept globally the `stopPropagation` prototype.

Below I've knocked up a very simple Snippet, you could extend to do more checks, making sure it's a link etc.

```js
const oStop = PointerEvent.prototype.stopPropagation;

PointerEvent.prototype.stopPropagation = function (e) {
  console.log(this.target);
  oStop.call(this);
}

function myFuncCanNotBeEdited(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}

document.body.onclick = e => console.log(e.target);
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;">
    <a href="#" onclick="myFuncCanNotBeEdited(event);">Edit</a>
    <a href="#">Remove</a>
  </div>
</body>
```